# Chroot Ubuntu Upgrade 14.04 Invalid?

Tags: 14.04, chroot

I got the Ubuntu Unity desktop on my Chromebook through Chroot. I realized there was a update ready, 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I start the process, and it gets to where the computer restarts. When I boot the computer back up, the Chroot is unable to start again. Did the update make the Chroot invalid??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you have before the update?

Comment: 12.04 Precise  I think

Comment: May want to edit that information into your question -- that'll bump the question to the top of the active list, as well as giving more information for people familiar with Chromebook and Chroot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a regular update with the GUI, do:

```
sudo enter-chroot -n <chroot_name>
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core python-apt
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Credit to [Crouton Wiki](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/upgrade%20chroot%20release)

Comment: Looks like you took it from https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Upgrade-chroot-release and want to take all the credit for it.

Comment: How else should I put it?

Comment: Use quote tags, but before that just look if four question has been asked and answered, took me less than a minute.